# Can't create a column over 4000 in size for a user, but can under SYS

Tags: oracle

I set the max_string_size parameter to extended, ran utl32k, and when I show the parameter it does display the value as extended.

When I create a table for SYS with a column sized over 4000, such as:

create table sys.mytable (col1 varchar2(8000));

The table is created fine.

However, if I create a table for a user I created, such as:

create table someuser.mytable (col1 varchar2(8000));

I get the "ORA-00910: specified length too long for its datatype" error.

Why can I create it under SYS, but not my user? Do I need to change something specific to the user to allow for extended?

Running 18 XE on Windows

Comment: You ran through the process in both the CDB and the PDB?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak Considering I don't know the difference, I'm going to assume I haven't -- First time having to work with Oracle. I'll look into that. Thank you.

Comment: @ObjectType How you solved this issue? I am getting the same behavior.